# Reference for solvability of Baumslag-Solitar groups

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, solvable-groups

I've been searching for a while and couldn't find any reference which provides necessary and sufficient conditions over $m,n$ for the group $BS(m,n)$ to be solvable. The only I could find is that it is solvable when $n=1$ or $m=1$, but I don't know if those are the only cases.
Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.